# Jquery - Tentando limpar um select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho dois dropdowns (select no html) um de UF e um de cidades, quando seleciono um estado quero acionar uma função para preencher o dropdown das cidades, recebendo o id do estado como parâmetro. Ele está trazendo todas as cidades do estado selecionado e removendo as cidades do estado anterior corretamente, o problema é que cidade selecionada anteriormente continua selecionada quando mudo o estado. Estou preso à versão 1.11 do Jquery, se isso tem alguma influência...
Já tentei fazer isso tanto pelo próprio Jquery quanto pelo javascript puro.

```
     <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a uf">
               <label for="cpEstado" class="select">
                     <select name="estado" id="cpEstado" data-theme="c"> <!--onchange="appUsuario.buscarCidades( this.value );">-->
                          <option value="" disabled selected>UF</option>
                      </select>
               </label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b cidade">
               <label for="cpCidade" class="select">
                      <select name="cidade" id="cpCidade" data-theme="c">
                          <option value="1" disabled selected>Cidade</option>
                      </select>
               </label>
       </div>
```

Esse é o código html onde estão os selects

```
$(document).on('change', '#cpEstado', function() {
            //document.getElementById("cpCidade").innerHTML = "<option id='padrao' disabled>Cidade</option>";
            //$('#cpCidade').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
            $('#cpCidade').empty();
            appUsuario.buscarCidades( this.value );});
```

Aqui é a função jquery que usei para fazer o preenchimento do cpCidade.

Tentei mudar o valor do item selecionado, e está assim agora:

[image: Ele muda]

Ele muda o texto do item mas não na parte do selecionado

Comment: Certo, e onde está o código para podermos analisar e lhe ajudar? Leia esse post para que você tenha sucesso nas suas perguntas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Não entendi `Ele está trazendo todas as cidades do estado selecionado e removendo as cidades do estado anterior corretamente` se está removendo as cidades do estado anterior como pode a cidade anterior estar selecionada? Não havia sido removida ao mudar o estado?

Comment: Com o código postado não dá para realizar testes. Se puder, coloque o código funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que você já tenha limpado a lista de options e atualizado com o novo resultado de cidades a partir do UF selecionado, feito isso remova qualquer atributo "selected" de todos os options do select de cidades, em seguida adicione o atributo "selected" no option desejado como no exemplo abaixo.

```js
//remove o atributo que mantem selecionado qualquer select
jQuery("#cpCidade option").removeAttr("selected");

//defino o index do select que desejo selecionar
var indexSelect = 2;

//adiciono o atributo selected ao option que desejo seleciona a partir do index 
jQuery("#cpCidade option").eq(indexSelect).attr("selected","selected");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a uf">
               <label for="cpEstado" class="select">
                     <select name="estado" id="cpEstado" data-theme="c"> <!--onchange="appUsuario.buscarCidades( this.value );">-->
                          <option value="" disabled selected>UF</option>
                      </select>
               </label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b cidade">
               <label for="cpCidade" class="select">
                      <select name="cidade" id="cpCidade" data-theme="c">
                          <option value="1">Cidade</option>
                          <option value="2" selected>Cidade 2</option>
                          <option value="3">Cidade 3</option>
                      </select>
               </label>
       </div>
```